# c# generics within foreach loop

Tags: c#, generics, foreach, type-conversion

I am confused with correct syntax in order to iterate on collection of generic classes. All these classes are derived FBase:

```
public abstract class FBase : FormElementBaseCL
{
    public FBase(FormElementGroupBaseCL parentElement, int linkedFieldID) : base(parentElement)
    {
        LinkedFieldID = linkedFieldID;
    }
    public int LinkedFieldID { get; set; }
}
```

Below are derived classes:

```
public abstract class FEdit<T> : FBase
{
    public FEdit(FormElementGroupBaseCL parentElement, int linkedFieldID) : base(parentElement, linkedFieldID)
    {
        LinkedFieldID = linkedFieldID;
    }

    public abstract T GetElementDTO();
}

public class FNumberEdit : FEdit<FieldElementNumberEditDTOCL>
{
    public FNumberEdit(FormElementGroupBaseCL parentElement, int linkedFieldID) : base(parentElement, linkedFieldID)
    {

    }

    public override FieldElementNumberEditDTOCL GetElementDTO()
    {
        /// implementation
    }
}

public class FTextEdit : FEdit<FieldElementTextEditDTOCL>
{
    public FTextEdit(FormElementGroupBaseCL parentElement, int linkedFieldID) : base(parentElement, linkedFieldID)
    {

    }

    public override FieldElementTextEditDTOCL GetElementDTO()
    {
        /// implementation
    }
}
```

Now, I want to iterate on List, however it says you have to specify 1 argument of type T:

```
            foreach (FEdit item in this.DataEntrySection.AllSubElements.FindAll(f => (f as FBase) != null).Cast<FBase>())
            {

            };
```

Question is, how to access item.GetElementDTO within loop?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do it this way. How would you know what is the return type of `GetElementDTO` inside the loop? Generics requires compile-time knowledge about the type. You might make it work with covariance and type constraints in `FEdit`, but that's different story.

Comment: Where do you iterate ? The solution might change depending on where you do it.

Comment: You don't have a `FEdit` type (`FEdit<T>` requires the generic type to be an actual type).  You might want to consider using an interface, but from what you have here it's hard to tell.

Comment: You can't use `FEdit` without a type argument: `FEdit<int>`, whatever. One thing to do is iterate over the items as `FBase`, and give `FBase` an abstract method `public abstract Object GetElementDTO();` That involves some kind of ugly logic in the loop to branch on the actual concrete type, but that's life. There's also a [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) approach, but that <s>might</s>would be overkill for what you're doing.